# Block a specific page on Tomcat 6 for a particular IP

Tags: security, tomcat, tomcat6

I need to grant the access a particular page (like `https://<ip-address>:<port>/resource/t.jsp`) only for requests coming from a particular IP address on Tomcat 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it in your context.xml as follows (e.g. for the /manager on 10.10.10.*):

```
<Context path="/manager"
 docBase="/usr/share/tomcat6-admin/manager"
 antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true">
 <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
    allow="10\.10\.10\..*"/>
</Context>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the security of this is important, don't try to do this using Tomcat only.  Put the server behind a firewall (like PF) that you can configure to block or allow requests based on the IP addresses.  You can make the rule as specific as you need to (such as allow only requests for port 80 from a particular source IP, etc.).